# docusign with tab with digits only

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I need to create docusign tabs which allows only 3 digits in c#

I have used docusign API but didnot find help

```
    signer.Tabs = new Tabs
    {
        TextTabs = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Text>
        {
            bankName,
            accountName
        },
        NumberTabs = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Number>
        {
            accountNumber
        }
    };
```

But I need to restrict only to enter 3 digits

The above will restrict digits only entry, but i need to allow only 3 digits entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `MaxLength` to set the maximum length of your tab.

In your code, it will be:

```
accountNumber.MaxLength = 3;
```